# how to make a variable not exceed the size limit of its type?

Tags: c++

so i want to know how to make a variable not exceed its number limit.

for example:

```
int x;
```

the size of x is four bytes

and since it is signed it starts from  (−2,147,483,648) to (2,147,483,647)

so if the input is larger than 2,147,483,647 it would not register and i want to prevent the program from letting a number larger than its number limit from being inputted

here is a code that will run into that problem:

```
int x[3];
x[0] = 12;
x[1] = 642;
x[2] = 800000000;
for (int z = 0;z < 3;z++)
{

        x[z] = x[z] * 3;


}
```

so how will i go about preventing x[z] from multiplying its self by 3 if the result is bigger than the number limit of the variable type?

Comment: Sometimes I miss Turbo Pascal - it had runtime range checking option. In C++, you can create your own class, define all arithmetic operators, and implement them so that they do the same thing.

Comment: look into std::numeric_limits

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c/20956705#20956705

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portable and obvious but unsatisfactory answer is that you have to check your operands beforehand:

```
int x[3];
x[0] = 12;
x[1] = 642;
x[2] = 800000000;
for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
{
    if (x[z] < std::numeric_limits<int>::max() / 3 &&
        x[z] > std::numeric_limits<int>::min() / 3) 
    {
        x[z] = x[z] * 3;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no portable, builtin facility to detect/prevent overflows, when/after they happen, but you can look into the sanitizers of clang (and I believe also gcc) Those will basically automatically instrument your code with those checks and e.g. terminate the program if an overflow occures.

If you want to have those checks only in debug mode, you can perform them as part of a `assert` instead of an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is "overflow".

Since GCC 5, there are builtins to detect this: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html

For previous versions, you'll have to find another implementation - there are probably polyfills somewhere.

For signed integers with rank at greater than or equal to `int`, you could also compile with `-fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow`.

Edit: if the output and both of the inputs are all the same type, there's a patch on the LKML here: https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/7/19/358

Comment: What about other compilers, such as Visual Studio, CLang, IAR Workbench, Greenhills?

Comment: GCC took the builtins from Clang. Visual Studio doesn't support it out of the box but you can get Clang/C2.

Comment: Man, Turbo C++ gets no love...

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Deficient compilers (which, let's be honest, everything but GCC/Clang are - but Clang doesn't have meaningful version numbers so I didn't mention it) are no worse than old versions of GCC/Clang.

Comment: What do you mean, Clang doesn't have meaningful version numbers? The feature first appeared in Clang 3.4, and we're at Clang 3.8 now. Clang ships a new release at the same time that LLVM does and they have the same version number.

Comment: @zneak Unless you use Apple clang. Or any other $vendor clang.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c) covers the topic nicely. However, if you want a quick-and-dirty solution, you can always get the result as a double, round it, and check if it causes an overflow. If it doesn't, cast to integer and use it. If it does, you can throw an error, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int xOriginal=1000000000;
    int xFinal=0;

    for (int i=0;i<1000;++i){
        double temp_result=i*(double)xOriginal;

        if (temp_result<std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
            && temp_result>std::numeric_limits<int>::min()){
            xFinal=(int)temp_result;
            cout <<"new x is : "<<xFinal <<endl;
        }else{
            assert(!"Integer overflow");
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
new x is : 0
new x is : 1000000000
new x is : 2000000000
a.out: test6.cpp:19: int main(): Assertion `!"Integer overflow"' failed.
```

Comment: `double integer_limit = 2147483647;` hard coded, sure?

Comment: I did say that it's a "quick-and-dirty solution", it's not meant to be portable. That being said, I'm merely using it as an example to demonstrate the type casting. Note that the OP didn't ask for a portable solution. Nice point though, I'll update the answer